# Scala lazy val explanation

Tags: scala, lazy-evaluation

I am taking the Functional Programming in Scala course on Coursera and I am having a hard time understanding this code snippet -

```
def sqrtStream(x: Double): Stream[Double] = {
  def improve(guess: Double): Double = (guess+ x/ guess) / 2
  lazy val guesses: Stream[Double] = 1 #:: (guesses map improve)
  guesses
}
```

This method would find 10 approximate square root of 4 in increasing order of accuracy when I would do sqrtSteam(4).take(10).toList.

Can someone explain the evaluation strategy of guesses here? My doubt is what value of guesses in substituted when the second value of guesses is picked up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start from simplified example:

```
 scala> lazy val a: Int  = a + 5
 a: Int = <lazy>

 scala> a
 stack overflow here, because of infinite recursion
```

So `a` is recalculating til it gets some stable value, like here:

```
scala> def f(f:() => Any) = 0 //takes function with captured a - returns constant 0
f: (f: () => Any)Int

scala> lazy val a: Int  = f(() => a) + 5
a: Int = <lazy>

scala> a
res4: Int = 5 // 0 + 5
```

You may replace `def f(f:() => Any) = 0` with `def f(f: => Any) = 0`, so `a` definition will look like it's really passed to the f: `lazy val a: Int = f(a) + 5`.

Streams use same mechanism - `guesses map improve` will be passed as parameter called by name (and lambda linked to the lazy `a` will be saved inside Stream, but not calculated until tail is requested), so it's like `lazy val guesses = #::(1, () => guesses map improve)`. When you call `guessess.head` -  tail will not be evaluated; `guesses.tail` will lazily return `Stream (improve(1), ?)`, `guesses.tail.tail` will be `Stream(improve(improve(1)), ?)` and so on.

Comment: Thanks. I never realized call by name parameter can be perceived as a function like this `def f(f:() => Any) = 0`. I guess this clarifies the main confusion that I had which was what value of guesses is used when guesses.tail is called. It seems like it will be the current value of the guesses with it's tail lazily computed.

Comment: Could you also explain what do you mean by this "and lambda linked to the lazy a will be saved inside Stream"? What is the lambda here? Also what would happen if we don't use lazy before guesses?

Comment: if you don't use lazy before guesses - you will receive compile-time error (vals doesn't allow any recursion).So lazy val is something between val and def - it's lazy as def, but initializes only once like val. When i'm talking about lambdas - i mean anonymous function. `() => x + 100500` is an anonymous function, which takes zero parameters and returns `x + 100500`. X doesn't mentioned here as function parameter, so this is a clojure linked to the x as free value. Stream just saves your clojure inside its inner state - so it will not be calculated at Stream's creation time.

Comment: it will be calculated and saved, when you will try to actually access the tail of Stream.

Comment: So is there a way that we can implement guesses as a def even if its inefficient ?

Comment: yeah! just put the def instead of lazy val :)

Comment: Also you said that vals don't allow recursion. But if just put this line in the REPL, this compiles without any error - `val guesses: Stream[Double] = 1 #:: (guesses map(_*4))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64508/discussion-between-piyush-and-dk14).

Comment: Yes. Values allows recursive definition but they take default initial value in case of infinite recursion (when value read directly without capturing): `val a = a + a + a` will return 0 instead of stack overflow error. So using lazy val is a little bit safer here

Answer (score 0):

You can easily find out what's going on by modifying the map function, as described in the [scaladoc example](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Stream):

```
scala> def sqrtStream(x: Double): Stream[Double] = {
     |   def improve(guess: Double): Double = (guess + x / guess) / 2
     |   lazy val guesses: Stream[Double] = 1 #:: (guesses map {n =>
     |     println(n, improve(n))
     |     improve(n)
     |   })
     |   guesses
     | }
sqrtStream: (x: Double)Stream[Double]
```

The output is:

```
scala> sqrtStream(4).take(10).toList
(1.0,2.5)
(2.5,2.05)
(2.05,2.000609756097561)
(2.000609756097561,2.0000000929222947)
(2.0000000929222947,2.000000000000002)
(2.000000000000002,2.0)
(2.0,2.0)
(2.0,2.0)
(2.0,2.0)
res0: List[Double] = List(1.0, 2.5, 2.05, 2.000609756097561, 2.0000000929222947, 2.000000000000002, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0)
```

Comment: My question is not what's going on. But more like how it's actually happening?

Answer (score 0):

The value of `guesses` is not substituted. A stream is like a list, but its elements are evaluated only when they are needed and then they stored, so next time you access them the evaluation will not be necessary. The reference to the stream itself does not change.

On top of the example **Αλεχει** wrote, there is a nice explanation in Scala API:
http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Stream